# Open Graph Meta Tags for Facebook in PHP

Tags: php, html, frontend

Why don't my Open Graph meta tags for Facebook load my photos when I post using a link?

```
echo '<meta property = "og: url" content = '.$link.'/>';
echo '<meta property = "og: type" content = "article" />'; 
echo '<meta property = "og: title" content = '.$title.'/>'; 
echo '<meta property = "og: description" content = '.$description.'/>'; 
echo '<meta property = "og: image" content = '.$main_photo.'/>';
```

Error:

> Invalid URL Provided og:image URL

Comment: `$main_photo = $article['photos'][0];
    $photos = $article['photos'];
    $title = $article['title'];
    $description = $article['description'];
    $autor = $article['autor'];
    $text = $article['text'];
    // $text = preg_replace('[{]', '<p>', $text);
    // $text = preg_replace('[}]', '</p>', $text);
    $intro = $article['intro'];
    $data = $article['data'];`

Comment: Remove the space from all `og: `

Comment: `  <?php
    echo '<meta property = "og:url" content = '.$link.'/>';
    echo '<meta property = "og:type" content = "article" />'; 
    echo '<meta property = "og:title" content = '.$title.'/>'; 
    echo '<meta property = "og:description" content = '.$description.'/>'; 
    echo '<meta property = "og:image" content = '.$main_photo.'/>';
  ?>`

Comment: errorrr (Invalid URL
Provided og:image URL,)

Comment: What is the value of `$main_photo`?